# Is there any way to assign resource limits after scheduling a pod? ( I would like to implement my own resource allocation policy)

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to create a way to specify resource limits after scheduling pods. Is it possible to do this? if yes, shall I implement it inside the kubelet or as a separate component?

Answer (score 1):

you can use kubectl patch command to update resource limits

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it by codes not kubectl. I would like to implement my own resource allocation policy.

Comment: You can use the kubernetes rest api hosted in kubernetes rest api server. All the things done via kubectl can be done by using kubernetes rest api.